# How do I create a queue of event delegates so you can raise them later?

Tags: c#, list, events, delegates

Is it possible to add an event (or delegate) to a list so that I can raise the even at a later point; like being able to cache the raise event to put it off to a later time (like buffering the events).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DelegateQueue {
    class Program {

        delegate void SomeTimeLaterDelegate(int myValue);
        static event SomeTimeLaterDelegate SomeTimeLater;
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SomeTimeLater += new SomeTimeLaterDelegate(AnswerAnotherDay);
            SomeTimeLater += new SomeTimeLaterDelegate(ItIsPossible);
            SomeTimeLater += new SomeTimeLaterDelegate(HenceTheNeed);

            List<Delegate> delegates = new List<Delegate>();

            SomeTimeLater.Invoke(100); // <== I need to trap this call in a list that I can invoke later.
            ///both the function call and the value that I'm passing.
            ///the problem is that there are lots of different events and they must be invoked in the order
            ///that they occoured (i.e. no skipping in the buffer)

        }

        static void AnswerAnotherDay(int howManyDays) {
            Console.WriteLine($"I did this {howManyDays}, later. Hurray for procrastination!");
        }

        static void ItIsPossible(int numberOfPossibilities) {
        ///that there is in invocation list for the event
        ///which means that I would have to call each function in that list and pass them the value

        }

        static void HenceTheNeed(int needs) {
        ///hence the need to queue the Invocation of the event to a later point
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible that there are multiple subscribers to the event, hence the need to buffer from the publisher's side as opposed to the subscriber's side.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please take a moment to read [ask] before you continue.  This question is way too broad and shows zero effort on your part.

Comment: What do you mean by "later time"? Cache events untill someone subscribes to this event queue?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can buffer the events either inside the publisher or inside the subscriber. In either case you'll probably need to store the EventArgs in a Queue<EventArgs>.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Buffer the events in the subscriber? It is important that the events take place in the sequence that there were originally called.

Comment: So when you created a list or queue and added delegates to it what happened?  You want to know if it's possible.  What happened when you tried it.  Did it work?

Comment: @user77232 the events will be stored in the correct order wherever you decide to store them. If you want to be 100% sure just store the `DateTime.UtcNow` together with the `EventArgs`, and sort by date before raising/consuming the queued events.

Comment: @Servy, I cant store the delegates themselves in the queue because I also need the parameters ( and I don't want to use multiple queues).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Yea, I'm going to use a stack to guarantee the order I just used a list in the example.

Comment: Something about this doesn't feel like a case for raising events. Maybe because of the emphasis on preserving the sequence. It sounds like you need to put a bunch of *something* in a queue and then process them FIFO. I think knowing what that something is would help. I also noticed that you have a queue but you're not putting anything into it or taking anything out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a literal example of what you're describing:

```
class Program
{
    delegate void SomeTimeLaterDelegate(int myValue);
    delegate void SayHelloDelegate(string name);

    static event SomeTimeLaterDelegate SomeTimeLaterEvent;
    static event SayHelloDelegate SayHelloLaterEvent;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeTimeLaterEvent += new SomeTimeLaterDelegate(AnswerAnotherDay);
        SayHelloLaterEvent += new SayHelloDelegate(SayHello);

        var eventsToRaise = new Queue<Action>();
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => SomeTimeLaterEvent.Invoke(100));
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => SayHelloLaterEvent.Invoke("Bob"));
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => SomeTimeLaterEvent.Invoke(200));
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => SayHelloLaterEvent.Invoke("John"));

        while (eventsToRaise.Any())
        {
            var eventToRaise = eventsToRaise.Dequeue();
            eventToRaise();
            //or eventToRaise.Invoke();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void AnswerAnotherDay(int howManyDays)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I did this {howManyDays}, later. Hurray for procrastination!");
    }

    static void SayHello(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}");
    }
}
```

Instead of a `Queue<Delegate>` this is a `Queue<Action>`. An `Action` represents invoking a method without passing any parameters or receiving a return value.

That might sound counter-intuitive because you *are* passing parameters. But you're not passing parameters *to* the actions. You're passing parameters from within the body of the actions.

This may or may not help:

When we declare

```
Action someAction = () => AnswerAnotherDay(5);
```

It's like declaring a method that looks like this:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    AnswerAnotherDay(5);
}
```

The method calls another method and passes an argument. But `MyMethod` itself doesn't receive any arguments. When we declare a method inline like that it doesn't have a name, so it's also called an *anonymous* method.

We could also declare an action that takes an argument, like this:

```
Action<string> action = (s) => SayHelloLater(s);
action("Bob");
```

The reason why I demonstrated using `Action` with no parameters is because you said that the queue might need to contain different types of events with different parameters.

If I was going to invoke the same method over and over again with different arguments then it would probably make more sense to put the arguments in the queue. Then each time we take arguments out of the queue we could raise the event with the next arguments.

Here's a possible simplification: Maybe you're thinking of a scenario where you need to raise events, but in this example we can do the exact same thing without events, and it's a little bit simpler.

Instead of defining delegates and events, adding certain methods as event handlers, and then creating actions that raise the events, we can just create actions that call the methods.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var eventsToRaise = new Queue<Action>();
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => AnswerAnotherDay(100));
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => SayHello("Bob"));
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => AnswerAnotherDay(200));
        eventsToRaise.Enqueue(() => SayHello("John"));

        while (eventsToRaise.Any())
        {
            var eventToRaise = eventsToRaise.Dequeue();
            eventToRaise();
            //or eventToRaise.Invoke();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void AnswerAnotherDay(int howManyDays)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I did this {howManyDays}, later. Hurray for procrastination!");
    }

    static void SayHello(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Therefore I can get the invocation list of the event, and create actions to call those methods with via an anonymous methods to simulate "events"?

Comment: I tacked on the last part just in case you didn't actually need events. But from that last comment it sounds like you actually do need to raise events, so in that case I'd actually use them.

Comment: or use Actions and queue those as Queue<Object>

Comment: There's no need to use `Object`. It's better to use the most specific type possible. So if everything in the queue is an `Action` then it should be `Queue<Action>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the challenge:

```
delegate void SomeTimeLaterDelegate(int myValue);
static event SomeTimeLaterDelegate SomeTimeLater;

static Queue<int> SomeTimeLaterQueue = new Queue<int>(); // Here we store the event arguments

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeTimeLater += new SomeTimeLaterDelegate(AnswerAnotherDay); // Subscribe to the event
    await Task.Delay(100);
    OnSomeTimeLaterDefered(10); // Raise an defered event
    await Task.Delay(100);
    OnSomeTimeLaterDefered(20); // Raise another defered event
    await Task.Delay(100);
    OnSomeTimeLaterDefered(30); // Raise a third defered event
    await Task.Delay(100);
    OnSomeTimeLaterFlush(); // Time to raise the queued events for real!
}

static void OnSomeTimeLaterDefered(int value)
{
    SomeTimeLaterQueue.Enqueue(value);
}
static void OnSomeTimeLaterFlush()
{
    while (SomeTimeLaterQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        SomeTimeLater?.Invoke(SomeTimeLaterQueue.Dequeue());
    }
}

static void AnswerAnotherDay(int howManyDays)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"I did this {howManyDays}, later. Hurray for procrastination!");
}
```

Output:

```
I did this 10, later. Hurray for procrastination!
I did this 20, later. Hurray for procrastination!
I did this 30, later. Hurray for procrastination!
```

Comment: Yes, except that the parameters could change. This only works if they are all the same. (which is possible for my exact solution but unlikely since its for g-code)

Comment: @user77232 I don't get it. Could you explain what you mean by "the parameters could change"? Do you mean that instead of integers your EventArgs are going to be mutable?

Comment: Yes, the event args are mutable. They could be string, other classes, interfaces or multiple args.

Comment: Strings are not mutable, but everything else could be. How are you going to solve this? It looks pretty tough.

Comment: Sorry not mutable. if I want var i'll declare them as var. Mutable was the wrong word.

Comment: @user77232 so what do you mean then by "the parameters could change"? If the EventArgs are immutable then what else could change?

Comment: Different events will have different parameters.

Comment: @user77232 you mean that you want to have a single event, that will be raised each time with different type of arguments? Why not having different events for each type of arguments?

Comment: You're last question is correct. I do want to have different events for each type of argument. (welcome to the hell that is me trying to explain myself; this is why the question got downvoted!)

Comment: @user77232 Have you figured out how to do it, or you are still in search for a solution?

Comment: I've decided that using the Action object with anonymous functions is the better method since its so clean an easy to understand. This feature isn't available on one of the platforms (tinyclr) that I once used, so I would have preferred a method that was more universal. I'm satisfied with the current solution for now though.